# Create A Hyperlink File Input Control

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way to create some html/jquery to display a hyperlink then when clicked it behaves like a file input control?

I would like to have the functionality of what this html does but the look of a hyperlink..

```
 <input id="fileToUpload" type="file" size="60" name="fileToUpload" class="input" value="myFile.xml"></div>
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, `<input>`'s styles are practically OS dependent. A quick workaround can be proxying the `click` event from a hyperlink to a hidden `<input>` of type `file`. I dont't if it is a cross-browser alternative or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the visibility of input to hidden. Trigger a click on the input when click on link

```
$('#fileLink').click(function(){
    $('#fileToUpload').click()
})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/mhVtA/

Not tested in all browsers